# Limiting value of angle in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an angle defined as such:

```
 accelerationX = acceleration.x * kFilteringFactor + accelerationX * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor);
 accelerationY = acceleration.y * kFilteringFactor + accelerationY * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor);
 double angle = atan2(accelerationY, -accelerationX) + M_PI/2;
```

I want to limit the value of angle to minimum -pi/3 and max pi/3. So if the value goes over pi/3, it should just stay at pi/3. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (angle < M_PI/-3)
{
    angle = M_PI/-3;
}
else if (angle > M_PI/3)
{
    angle = M_PI/3;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add:

```
angle = (angle < -M_PI/3 ? -M_PI/3 : (angle > M_PI/3 ? M_PI/3 : angle));
```

Comment: While this gets the job done, is this really something you want to be looking at... ever? We spend a lot more time reading our code than we do writing it.

Comment: Come on, for something that simple, you don't need more than one line. Keeping the code concise also improves readability.

Comment: @Simon, Of course! We are just comparing two values here, not anything complex. So one line of code is better!